# Is there a way of finding an array that is not included in another array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a list of date information, one column (called "dates") is an array of dates, it represents a sequence of dates.  I am trying to find only those arrays of dates that are not included in other arrays of dates.

I have tried using a cursor and comparing with <@ but I end up with nonsense, totally confused how to do it.

Here is the table:

| days | start_date | end_date | dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05,2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 3 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05,2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 2 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 1 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-03 00:00:00 | 2023-09-03 |
| 3 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05,2023-09-04 |
| 2 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05,2023-09-04 |
| 1 | 2023-09-04 | 2023-09-04 00:00:00 | 2023-09-04 |
| 2 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 2023-09-05 | 2023-09-05 00:00:00 | 2023-09-05 |
| 1 | 2023-09-06 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06 |
| 4 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21,2023-09-20,2023-09-19,2023-09-18 |
| 3 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 | 2023-09-20,2023-09-19,2023-09-18 |
| 2 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-19 00:00:00 | 2023-09-19,2023-09-18 |
| 1 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | 2023-09-18 |
| 3 | 2023-09-19 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21,2023-09-20,2023-09-19 |
| 2 | 2023-09-19 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 | 2023-09-20,2023-09-19 |
| 1 | 2023-09-19 | 2023-09-19 00:00:00 | 2023-09-19 |
| 2 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21,2023-09-20 |
| 1 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-09-20 00:00:00 | 2023-09-20 |
| 1 | 2023-09-21 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21 |
| 1 | 2023-09-23 | 2023-09-23 00:00:00 | 2023-09-23 |

And this is the results I am hoping to get:

| days | start_date | end_date | dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2023-09-03 | 2023-09-06 00:00:00 | 2023-09-06,2023-09-05,2023-09-04,2023-09-03 |
| 4 | 2023-09-18 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 | 2023-09-21,2023-09-20,2023-09-19,2023-09-18 |
| 1 | 2023-09-23 | 2023-09-23 00:00:00 | 2023-09-23 |

Please help, I am stuck, and thank you in advance.

Comment: 1)To your question add the code you tried as well as any error messages that resulted. 2) What you show in the `dates` column is not an array. What is that data type for `dates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be fairly trivial: just get those entries that are not contained in other entries:

```
SELECT d.start_date, d.end_date
FROM dates AS d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM dates AS d2
                  WHERE d2.start_date <= d.start_date
                   AND d2.end_date >= d.end_date
                   AND (d.start_date, d.end_date) <> (d2.start_date, d2.end_date));
```

Comment: Ah, thank you... that works, so simple :)